# contentEditable="true": Text appearing infront of input cursor

Tags: html, angular, forms, dom

I am using angular.

My code:

```
<div contentEditable="true" attr.placeholder="{{placeholder}}" 
    [textContent]="model"
    (input)="[model=$event.target.textContent,inputed($event)]">
</div>
```

I am trying to build a resposive website. The component above works well in the web version, even when I test it on the web for different sizes, using google chrome. The problem comes when I try to use the form in a mobile device, using safari browser. The Input cursor does not move, text appears in front of it. text appears backwards.

For example if I type *Hello world.* it appears as *.dlrow olleH*. The cursor stays at the far left.

If I remove `model=$event.target.textContent` it works as expected even on the mobile browsers. Is there a way to make it work normally without having to remove this piece of code?

Comment: Did you try with two-way binding `[(ngModel)]="model"` instead?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I am using the component in a reactive form so ngModel won’t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.

Old problematic code:

HTML:

```
<div contentEditable="true" attr.placeholder="{{placeholder}}" 
    [textContent]="model"
    (input)="inputed($event)">
</div>
```

Typescript file:

```
@Input() model = '';

inputed(event){
    this.model = event.target.textContent;
    this.propagateChange(this.model.trim());
}
```

New code, the solution

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" attr.placeholder="{{placeholder}}" 
    [textContent]="model"
    (input)="inputed($event)" >
</div>
```

Typescript file

```
@Input() model = '';

inputed(event){
    this.propagateChange(event.target.textContent);
  }
```

There is more code in the typescript file that allows for the component to be used as a form input in a reactive form. Below is the full code for the typescript file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-textarea',
  templateUrl: './custom-textarea.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-textarea.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomTextareaComponent),
    }
  ]
})

export class CustomTextareaComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  @Input() placeholder:string = "";

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      this.model = obj;
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    // We don’t want to do anything at this event,
    // so we can implement the interface with an empty function.
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // We don’t want to do anything at this event,
    // so we can implement the interface with an empty function.
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  @Input() model = '';

  inputed(event){
    this.propagateChange(event.target.textContent);
  }

}
```