# Angular and Typescript - set cursur position multiple child element in contenteditable div(tried almost all articles)

Tags: angular, typescript, contenteditable

Can some one help me to get this resolved? [Here is the stackblitz code I am working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjhbb6)

If you know any workaround, please let me know.

The Caret/cursur keeps going to start position and typing backward.can anyone help me to get this resolved in Angular(Typescript)?I had to choose div instead of textarea as I have links.

```
(event.target as HTMLInputElement).focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll', true, null);
document.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186935/9953550) answer your question?

Comment: No didnt work. I have to use innerHTML as I have to show as link and I need to replace content as they type.I tried your example as well. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pndmep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html .
Below replace content is causing issue which is required for my requirement.

.replace('foo', '<a href="www.bar.com" title="Description">bar</a>')

Comment: can you please create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) of your current code so that I can understand everything well.

Comment: @YulePale. Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjhbb6

Comment: You have to manually restore caret position of you programmatically update content of any editable element. Contenteditable here is no different from regular input, except caret position is harder to get/set

Comment: Hi @waterplea, do you know how to set caret position in angular/Typescript.I have tried several option.I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Vanilla ranges accept setting offset. However it is in characters only in text nodes, in other nodes offset goes over child nodes. Here's a function I wrote to set offset in characters, this would probably help you: https://gist.github.com/waterplea/fcb68a1fc39b677c33c0446159b46a6b

Comment: I agree @waterplea. I have tried various ways none of them works because angular 'refreshes' the caret postion when you change the HTML. The working answer should address the 'caret resetting'. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62829289/9953550) does that.

Comment: Editing doesn't always happen at the end, you need a generic solution. And it is not Angular that is doing so, this is how HTML works. If you programmatically change editable value caret does not know where it stands in the new value.

Answer (score 2):

here's one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442) from StackOverflow

```
setCaretToEnd(target/*: HTMLDivElement*/) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  range.selectNodeContents(target);
  range.collapse(false);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  target.focus();
  range.detach(); // optimization

  // set scroll to the end if multiline
  target.scrollTop = target.scrollHeight; 
}
```

Here's the updated [stackblitz plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9bfrpz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=editor)